# Not able to run on Riggeti from Azure

Tags: qiskit, azure-quantum, rigetti

Trying to run [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/quickstart-microsoft-qiskit?pivots=platform-rigetti) (**Submit a circuit with Qiskit to Azure Quantum**) on Riggeti from Azure, with a US account, but job **failed** with this error on the Job management console of Azure:

```
Error code: QIRPreProcessingFailed
Error message: No match found for output recording set converter from outputrecordingset.v2.labeled to outputrecordingset.v1.nonlabeled
```

And this error in my python console when running `job_monitor()`:

```
Job Status: job incurred error
```

(It is working when I try IONQ or Quantinuum)

**Any suggestions?**

BTW - one of the main differences between running Ionq/Quantinuum to running on Rigetti is the `_translate_input` function.
In the first two, the method is overided in the context of backend, to support non QIR circuit.
In Rigetti they use the default `_translate_input` of `AzureBackend`.

Rigetti, under `AzureBackend` general object:

```
    def _translate_input(self, circuit, data_format, input_params, to_qir_kwargs={}):
    """ Translates the input values to the format expected by the AzureBackend. """
    if data_format != "qir.v1":
        target = self.name()
        raise ValueError(f"{data_format} is not a supported data format for target {target}.")

    logger.info(f"Using QIR as the job's payload format.")
    from qiskit_qir import to_qir_bitcode, to_qir

    # Set of gates supported by QIR targets.
    from qiskit_qir import SUPPORTED_INSTRUCTIONS as qir_supported_instructions

    capability = input_params["targetCapability"] if "targetCapability" in input_params else "AdaptiveExecution"

    if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        logger.debug(f"QIR:\n{to_qir(circuit, capability, **to_qir_kwargs)}")

    # all qir payload needs to define an entryPoint and arguments:
    if not "entryPoint" in input_params:
        input_params["entryPoint"] = "main"
    if not "arguments" in input_params:
        input_params["arguments"] = []

    # We'll transpile automatically to the supported gates in QIR unless explicitly skipped.
    if not input_params.get("skipTranspile", False):
        circuit = transpile(circuit, basis_gates = qir_supported_instructions)

        # We'll only log the QIR again if we performed a transpilation.
        if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
            logger.debug(f"QIR (Post-transpilation):\n{to_qir(circuit, capability, **to_qir_kwargs)}")

    qir = bytes(to_qir_bitcode(circuit, capability, **to_qir_kwargs))
    return (qir, data_format, input_params)
```

In Qunatinuum, under `QuantinuumBackend`:

```
    def _translate_input(self, circuit, data_format, input_params, to_qir_kwargs={}):
    """ Translates the input values to the format expected by the AzureBackend. """
    if input_params["targetCapability"] == "openqasm":
        return (circuit.qasm(), data_format, input_params)
    else:
        # Not using openqasm, assume qir then:
        return super()._translate_input(circuit, "qir.v1", input_params, to_qir_kwargs)
```

In Ionq, under `IonQBackendBackend`:

```
    def _translate_input(self, circuit, data_format, input_params, to_qir_kwargs={}):
    """ Translates the input values to the format expected by the AzureBackend. """
    if data_format == "ionq.circuit.v1":
        ionq_circ, _, _ = qiskit_circ_to_ionq_circ(circuit, gateset=self.gateset())
        input_data = {
            "gateset": self.gateset(),
            "qubits": circuit.num_qubits,
            "circuit": ionq_circ,
        }
        return (IonQ._encode_input_data(input_data), data_format, input_params)
    else:
        return super()._translate_input(circuit, data_format, input_params, to_qir_kwargs)
```

One more difference is `content_type` of `run()` function. Looks like in Rigetti they mistakenly took the same `str` as `input_data_format`:
[image]

This is not the case in Quantinuum:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely because you have a pre-release versions of qiskit-qir and pyqir installed in your environment. These pre-release versions produce [QIR](https://github.com/qir-alliance/qir-spec) that is not recognized by the Azure Quantum service.

The problem can be solved by uninstalling all versions of pyqir, pyqir-*, and qiskit-qir, and then installing azure-quantum[qiskit] (which will install the correct dependency versions).